# How to import excel file using dynamic sheet name in SSIS

Tags: excel, ssis, script-component, script-task

I am trying to import excel file and load it into sql sever database and i have created dynamic folder path and the file name as dynamic  but my only issue is that i am not able to create dynamic sheet names.  Users can put a new excel file with different sheet name each time they update the file so i am trying to find out either a way to rename the excel sheet or use the sheet name as variable.  I have goggled online but i don't see step by step instruction and i get error every time i try to follow their instruction. In the excel file, it is always one sheet only.  Thanks.

Comment: Can you give an example of an error you got, and what you were trying when you got it?

Comment: Check out [OpenRowset from variable](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic637794-148-1.aspx). Someone has answered similar question.

Comment: i checked the link but did not help me, i don't have multiple sheets in my excel file but it is only one sheet. thanks

Comment: Cant you create a process that would open the excel and rename the sheet? This is out of SSIS Scope IMO, but doable via an external script.

Comment: Did you try script task or script component